# Big braces both on left and right of column or array

Tags: braces

I'm trying to type a column with seven elements and some vertical big braces on its left and right. The code I use is

```
\[
\begin{array}{rcl}
& \Gamma & \\
\multirow{3}{*}{$\mathcal{D}_3 \bigg\{$} 
& \mathcal{D}_1 & \\
& A & \\
& \mathcal{D}_2 & \multirow{2}{*}{$\bigg\} \mathcal{D}_5$} \\
& B & \\
& \mathcal{D}_4 & \\
& C &
\end{array}
\]
```

which produces

[image: this image]

but I'd like to produce bigger and closer to the middle column braces such that the one on the left includes elements D_1 to D_2 and the one on the right includes D_2 to D_4.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Ok, I used the code of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/braces-on-either-side-of-a-list), which introduces a new command, and made it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `multirow` package comes with another package `bigdelim` for such purposes.  It is probably easiest to add an extra column for these brackets and kill the spacing between columns with `@{}` in the template:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{r@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}l}
    && \Gamma && \\
    \multirow{3}{*}{$\mathcal{D}_3$} & \ldelim\{{3}{1em}{} & \mathcal{D}_1 && \\
    && A && \\
    && \mathcal{D}_2 & \rdelim\}{3}{1em}{} &\multirow{3}{*}{$\mathcal{D}_5$} \\
    && B && \\
    && \mathcal{D}_4 && \\
    && C &&
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @frabala: Don't for get to upvote the answer `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with some additional corrections of horizontal spacing in the future:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\[
%\begin{array}{rcl}
\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
& \Gamma & \\
%\multirow{3}{*}{$\mathcal{D}_3 \bigg\{$} 
\multirow{3}{*}{$\mathcal{D}_3 \Bigg\{$} 
& \mathcal{D}_1 & \\
& A & \\
& \mathcal{D}_2 & \multirow{2}{*}{$\bigg\} \mathcal{D}_5$} \\
& B & \\
& \mathcal{D}_4 & \\
& C &
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I already found a solution but yours is simpler. :)